# Find file paths that have spaces

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to select file paths that contain spaces and are not wrapped in quotes.  In addition, I only want paths that begin with a volume letter (e.g., C:\, D:\, E:) and I want to ignore any switches or commands that come after the path.

Take for instance the following list, I have highlighted in bold all of the text I want to match and return:

---

**C:\This path has spaces\system.sys** -switch /command
C:\Thispathhasnospaces\filename.exe
\sytem32\ThisDidNotBeginWithADriveLetter\something.doc
**D:\This path also has spaces\something.xlsx**
"C:\I don't care if it is wrapped in quotes\something.abc" -switch

---

So far what I have come up with is:

`^\w:\(.+)(.\w\w\w)`

Which sort of works, but it selects paths both with spaces and without spaces.  It also doesn't select the full filename if the path as a four character extension, such as .xlsx

Any help would be very much appreciated.  If you do post a better regex, if you added some explanation it would really help because I am trying to learn it.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of switch and command? It always starts with `-` or `/`, preceded by a space? A path can contain `{space}-`, so `-` preceded by a space and not succeeded by a space? Getting complex, and still not safe... (doesn't seem to be possible to be fully unambiguous)

Comment: Well, maybe a better way to look at it is I am only interested in the file path portion.  So ignore anything after the file name portion.

Comment: I see, when there is always a filename-dot-extension this will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go by

```
^[A-Z]:\\.+\s.+\.\S+
```

- `^` is an anchor for the start of the string
- `[A-Z]:\\` matches a letter followed by colon and backslash
- `.+` matches any character, 1 or more times
- `\s` matches a single space
- `.+\.\S+` matches any characters followed by dot and non-spaces

See https://regex101.com/r/fC5tF8/2 for a demo

Comment: Yes!  This seems to do just what I need.  Also, thank you so much for the demo.  Very informative.  You rocked my face off!

Comment: btw, you can shorten your regex: `[^\s]` is the same as `\S`

Comment: @Bohemian indeed it is

Answer (score 0):

a regex I would use is

```
^\w:[^\s]+[\.]*[^\s]+
```

this will find anything that starts with a alphanumeric and contains no spaces.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for the reply, but I want the paths that do contain spaces.  The paths that do not contain spaces I want to ignore.  Also, I want to ignore any commands and switches after the filename portion of the path.